# Too many open files error on webserver with wordpress site on litespeed server

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, ubuntu-18.04, litespeed

I am running a wordpress site on a litespeed webserver, caching enabled using the litespeed plugin, with cloudflare as a CDN.

Every few days or so, the logs start filling with the below error. Not once, but literally 1000 times a second. Needless to say this yields multiple problems, not in the least a Cloudflare 520 error which makes my site partly unreachable.

> error.log.2019_07_11.02:2019-07-11 00:54:29.349819 [ERROR] [*:443]
>   HttpListener::acceptConnection(): Accept failed:Too many open files!
>   error.log.2019_07_11.02:2019-07-11 00:54:29.349823 [ERROR] [*:80]
>   HttpListener::acceptConnection(): Accept failed:Too many open files!

When this is happening, logged in users can just continue to use the site, but people not logged in are served the Cloudflare 520 error page. When I search for this problem, people suggest to increase the nofiles in the /etc/security/limits.conf

I did that, but to no avail. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Could you run `lsof -n > lsof_-n_$HOSTNAME_$(date +%F_%H%M%S).txt` when you notice the issue? Search which file descriptors are open by web server or application server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MirceaVutcovici! I will certainly try it next time I notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [wiki](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:increasing-os-file-descriptor-limit) ? and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :). Yes I have, to no avail, other than that it happens now more infrequently. But for that I have set all file limits to >100k, which is sort of rediculous